# How do I change all Pluma settings

Tags: pluma

Using Ubuntu Mate 21.04

I guess I've done something wrong here, but when I select File/Open in Pluma, the chooser lists files/directories in reverse alphabetical order. How do I change this setting?

I could use 'Open with File Manager' which displays alphabetically, but it's an extra click.

Comment: Can you not click the top of the column to change the sort order?

Comment: You're right of course. I think I was clicking the first name in the list instead of the caption at the top. My mistake; I'm getting too old for this stuff...